# How to use RSpec without Rails?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

What is the process for doing TDD in Ruby with RSpec without Rails?

Do I need a Gemfile? Does it only need rspec in it?

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I'd assume it's pretty much the same as without, as there's no direct connection between rails and rspec.

Comment: vimeo tutorial here: http://blog.codeship.com/install-rspec-tutorial/

Comment: It's a bit hard to see from the heading on the page and the title of the video, but this seems to be for both Rails and Rails-free Ruby projects.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The process is as follows:

Install the rspec gem from the console:

```
gem install rspec
```

Then create a folder (we'll name it root) with the following content:

root/my_model.rb

root/spec/my_model_spec.rb

```
#my_model.rb
class MyModel
  def the_truth
    true
  end
end

#spec/my_model_spec.rb

require_relative '../my_model'

describe MyModel do
  it "should be true" do
    MyModel.new.the_truth.should be_true
  end
end
```

Then in the console run

```
rspec spec/my_model_spec.rb
```

voila!

Answer (score 43):

From within your projects directory...

```
gem install rspec
rspec --init
```

then write specs in the spec dir created and run them via

```
rspec 'path to spec' # or just rspec to run them all
```

Answer (score 13):

The workflows around `gem install rspec` are flawed. Always use Bundler and Gemfile to ensure consistency and avoid situations where a project works correctly on one computer but fails on another.

Create your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'

gem 'rspec'
```

Then execute:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rspec --init
```

The above will create `.rspec` and `spec/spec_helpers.rb` for you.

Now create your example spec in `spec/example_spec.rb`:

```
describe 'ExampleSpec' do
  it 'is true' do
    expect(true).to be true
  end
end
```

And run the specs:

```
% bundle exec rspec
.

Finished in 0.00325 seconds (files took 0.09777 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: This makes sense and is probably a best practice. However, it also makes the assumption that the purpose of using rspec here is automatically an open source and/or shared project.  For the case where you just want to use rspec for local testing of say a user script, this may be overkill.

Comment: I'd hardly call those few lines "overkill", and would advise anyone to use bundler as shown in this excellent answer!